# Java program does not copy file properly using byte array

Tags: java, file, arrays

I am trying to make a program which will take the file as input, and save it to some copy it to some other location. But unfortunately output files I get are corrupted. What am I doing wrong?

File class:

```
package server.client;

import java.util.Vector;

public class File {
public byte [] inArray;
public Vector <byte [] > inVector;
public byte [] outArray;
public Vector <byte [] > outVector;
public String name;
public String savePath;

public File(String name)
{
    outVector=new Vector<byte []>();
    this.name=name;

}

public File(byte [] array,String name){
    this.inArray=array;
    this.name=name;
    System.out.println("Input has "+inArray.length+" bytes");
    int vectorSize=inArray.length /1024 + 1;
    System.out.println("vector size: "+ vectorSize);
    inVector= new Vector<byte []>(vectorSize);
    int c=0;
    for(int i=0; i<vectorSize;i++){

        if(vectorSize==1){
            byte [] temp=new byte[inArray.length];
            for(int j=0;i< inArray.length;i++){
                temp[j]=inArray[j];
            }
            inVector.add(temp);
            System.out.println("Input has 1 byte vector");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Input has multiple byte vectors");
            byte [] temp=new byte[1024];
            for(int j=0;j< 1024; j++){
            if(c==array.length)
                break;
            temp[j]=array[c];
            c++;
            }
            inVector.add(temp);
        }

    }
}

public void addToVector(byte [] ar){
    outVector.add(ar);
}

public void prepareOutArray(){
    int c=0;
    for(int i=0;i<outVector.size(); i++){
        byte[] temp=outVector.elementAt(i);
        for(int j=0;j<temp.length;j++){
            c++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("File has "+c +" bytes");

    outArray=new byte[c];
    int f=0;
    for(int i=0;i<outVector.size(); i++){
        byte[] temp=outVector.elementAt(i);
        for(int j=0;j<temp.length;j++){
            if(f==1024*i + j)
                break;
            outArray[f]+=temp[j];
            f++;
        }
    }
}
}
```

main class:

```
package server.client;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ServerClient  {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("File name (including format:");
    String nm=input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("File location:");
    String path=input.nextLine();
    Path myPath=Paths.get(path);
    byte [] array=null;
    try {
        array=Files.readAllBytes(myPath);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ServerClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.out.println("couldnt read the file");
    }

    File fileObject=new File(array,nm);

    System.out.println("copying item");
    File outputObject=new File("whattoDO.txt");
    for(int i=0;i< fileObject.inVector.size() ;i++){
        outputObject.addToVector(fileObject.inVector.elementAt(i));
    }

    System.out.println("C:/Users/Ejub/Documents/"+outputObject.name);
    FileOutputStream fileOut=null;
    outputObject.prepareOutArray();
    System.out.println("");
    try {
        fileOut=new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/Ejub/Documents/"+outputObject.name);
        fileOut.write(outputObject.outArray);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ServerClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.out.println("couldnt write to file1");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ServerClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.out.println("couldnt write to file2");
    }
```

Comment: What errors are you seeing?  What have you tried in terms of debugging?

Comment: There are no errors. Program does copy a file, but that copied file has different size in bytes (compared to the original file). I've been trying to modify the File class for 1 hour, but the output files I get are still corrupted.

Comment: And what is the difference in size?  Is it always off by that amount no matter how big the original file is or is the difference some constant percentage or is it random? Include this kind of information in your question.  People are more likely to assist you if they don't need to play comment tag.

Comment: Thanks for noticing me about that, I'll keep it in mind. 
If file is smaller than 1024 bytes, than as the output program produces the same size file, but it is somehow still corrupted (I tried that on txt files). Files which are larger than 1024 bytes are outputted with about 100-500 additional bytes length.

Answer (score 1):

Must start by saying stay away from `Vector`.  Just google "java Vector bad" or similar.

I'm not sure why you are keeping a list of byte arrays.  And I don't see where you populate the list with the single `byte[]` you read.

At the risk of downvotes for not *really* answering your question, I'm simply going off of your text

> I am trying to make a program which will take the file as input, and save it to some copy it to some other location.

I don't see why it isn't something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("File name to move?");
    String name = scanner.next();

    System.out.println("Destination?");
    String destination = scanner.next();

    File current = new File(name);
    File movedFile = new File(destination);

    try {
        byte[] content = Files.readAllBytes(current.toPath());
        Files.write(movedFile.toPath(),content, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to read from " +
              current.getAbsolutePath() + ", or write to " + movedFile.getAbsolutePath(),e);
    }        
}
```